# Blend the png transparent texture as a map with a color

Tags: three.js

I have a transparent png and need to blend(cover) with a color.
This is my code but show me just png:

```
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {
        map: new TextureLoader().load("pic.png"),
        color: new THREE.Color(0x0000ff),
        transparent: true,
        needsUpdate: true,
    }
)
```

My solution:
Create 2 meshes.
mesh 1 with png texture and mesh 2 with color and overlap them. is it correct way?

Comment: If you just want to blend a texture with a color, you don't need two meshes. Your code snippet should already work. I've created a small live example that shows how it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/42u701t9/